# How to find a list of hosts in the local area network?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a list of active IPs in the LAN using Python. I have tried the following code (which was suggested by someone else) but it does not output any Hosts:

```
def pinger(job_q, results_q):
    """
    Do Ping
    :param job_q:
    :param results_q:
    :return:
    """
    DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    while True:
        ip = job_q.get()

        if ip is None:
            break
        try:
            subprocess.check_call(['ping', '-c1', ip],
                                  stdout=DEVNULL)
            results_q.put(ip)
        except:
            pass

def get_my_ip():
    """
    Find my IP address
    :return:
    """
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
    ip = s.getsockname()[0]
    s.close()
    return ip

def map_network(pool_size=255):
    """
    Maps the network
    :param pool_size: amount of parallel ping processes
    :return: list of valid ip addresses
    """
    ip_list = list()

    # get my IP and compose a base like 192.168.1.xxx
    ip_parts = get_my_ip().split('.')
    base_ip = ip_parts[0] + '.' + ip_parts[1] + '.' + ip_parts[2] + '.'

    # prepare the jobs queue
    jobs = multiprocessing.Queue()
    results = multiprocessing.Queue()

    pool = [multiprocessing.Process(target=pinger, args=(jobs, results)) for i in range(pool_size)]

    for p in pool:
        p.start()

    # cue hte ping processes
    for i in range(1, 255):
        jobs.put(base_ip + '{0}'.format(i))

    for p in pool:
        jobs.put(None)

    for p in pool:
        p.join()

    # collect he results
    while not results.empty():
        ip = results.get()
        ip_list.append(ip)

    return ip_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Mapping...')
    lst = map_network()
    print(lst)
```

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: `tried the following code which was suggested by someone else` - Have you tried to understand how the code works? Does either `get_my_ip` or `pinger` work? When you try to use the code in `map_network` to find a single, specific ip address that you know exists does it find that *host*?

Comment: im very sorry. i did not have a look at it. silly me. so do i have to edit this based on my network and system or is something that works on any device ?

Comment: This is not an answer, but I think the protocol you need is DHCP, and there is a similar question at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580544/python-dhcp-client

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.